# Does CancelEdit work on TListItem in a TListView in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, listview

If I try

```
ListView1.items[0].EditCaption;
```

it works as expected allowing me to edit the first items caption, however if while editing I try

```
ListView1.items[0].CancelEdit;
```

It does not cancel the editing.  Is there some concept I'm missing, is it a bug, or is the help wrong?

This seems to be a problem in Delphi 2007 and XE2 (and probably others).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is a problem with the native control, the VCL does as [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761238%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (calls `ListView_EditLabel(Handle, -1);`), but to no effect. According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761260%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) of `ListView_GetEditControl`, sending the list view a `WM_CANCELMODE` should also work, which it doesn't.

A test here shows the below works,

```
winapi.windows.SetFocus(ListView1.Handle);
```

interestingly `ListView1.SetFocus` doesn't.